# Is $\Delta^{-1}$ a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-analysis

Is the inverse Laplacian $\Delta^{-1}: H^{m+2}(M)\mapsto H^m(M)|1$ a bounded operator? Where $M$ is  a compact manifold and $H^m(M)|1$ means its elements $f \in H^m(M)$ and $\langle1,f\rangle=\int_{M}f dx=0$. Could anyone give me a rough proof, or give me some references. I can't find any reference which give a detailed proof of this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not only bounded, but compact—this all follows from the theory of elliptic regularity for essentially self-adjoint elliptic operators on a closed manifold (e.g., the metric Laplacian on a closed Riemannian manifold). Actually, any reference on pseudodifferential operators should discuss this example in some detail.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thanks for your comments. I am not familiar with this area, so could you suggest me some explicit reference?

Comment: For instance, any detailed account of the Atiyah–Singer index theorem from the heat kernel perspective, e.g, Roe's *Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods* or Gilkey's *Invariance theory, the heat equation, and the Atiyah–Singer index theorem*.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić That's great! It's really help. Thank you very much.